# AttributeError at 'AutoShape' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, django, yolov5

I want to run my yolov5 model in a web application. But when loading the model I get this error.

```
def detect(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        files = request.FILES.getlist("file")
        for file in files:
            model = yolov5.load(
                "best.pt"
            )
            prediction = model.predict(file)
            prediction.append(prediction)

        return render(
            request,
            "pages/models.html",
            {"predictions": prediction},
        )
```

I am getting this error while loading the model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhl1C.png)